# isDst in Time Zone in C language

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to figure out on making a time from the values i choose (dynamically)

I tried giving a date of 31st march 03:10pm and trying to go back a month with 03:10Pm which is 28th Feb 03:10Pm. But i am getting a value as 04:10Pm.

I set the isdst = -1 to do this bit; but still it fails.

Any ideas.

```
Tm->tm_mon = ReportMonth;
  Tm->tm_mday = ReportEndDay;
Tm->tm_hour = TimeOfDay/60;
  Tm->tm_min  = TimeOfDay%60;
  Tm->tm_sec  = 59;
  Tm->tm_isdst = -1;
```

Comment: Which date are you saying "isdst"?

Comment: Please advise if you are still working this problem.  Did you use `mktime()` and `localtime()`?  If so, please show how.